# Swift: Change button image in table view on click

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uibutton

I created an Xcode project for iPhone using Swift, with Parse for the backend. My current problem is with creating a todo list application as one tab of a larger application.

Inside of a custom prototype cell, I want to have a checkbox button that changes its image when clicked as well as changing the isChecked:Bool variable for that cell. I've gotten most of the way there, but I've run into a brick wall regarding setting and accessing the appropriate variables for this button.

**Edit: Thanks to the answer below and other resources, I have finally written working code for this checkbox functionality. Essentially, the button's tag property is set equal to the indexPath.row of the PFObject. As my original question was a bit broad, I am updating my code below so that it might help other new developers who are working on similar functionality. There may be better ways, but this seems to work.**

//  TasksVC.swift

```
var taskObjects:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)    
    self.fetchAllObjects()
}

func fetchAllObjects() {

    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Task")

    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    query.orderByAscending("dueDate")
    query.addAscendingOrder("desc")

    //fetches values within pointer object
    query.includeKey("deal")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (tasks: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            var temp:NSArray = tasks! as NSArray
            self.taskObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()

            println("Fetched objects from server")

        } else {
            println(error?.userInfo)
        }
    }
}


//MARK: - Tasks table view
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.taskObjects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TaskCell

    var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yy"

    var task:PFObject = self.taskObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    cell.desc_Lbl?.text = task["desc"] as? String
    cell.date_Lbl.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(task["dueDate"] as NSDate)

    //value of client within Deal pointer object
    if let deal = task["deal"] as? PFObject {
        // deal column has data
        if let client = deal["client"] as? String {
            // client has data
            cell.client_Lbl?.text = client
        }
    }

    //set the tag for the cell's UIButton equal to the indexPath of the cell
    cell.checkbox_Btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.checkbox_Btn.addTarget(self, action: "checkCheckbox:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.checkbox_Btn.selected = task["isCompleted"] as Bool

    if (task["isCompleted"] != nil) {
            cell.checkbox_Btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:(cell.checkbox_Btn.selected ? "CheckedCheckbox" : "UncheckedCheckbox")), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    return cell

}

func checkCheckbox(sender:UIButton!) {
    var senderBtn:UIButton = sender as UIButton
        println("current row: \(senderBtn.tag)")

    //retrieve the PFObject for the row we have selected
    var task:PFObject = self.taskObjects.objectAtIndex(senderBtn.tag) as PFObject
        println("objectID: \(task.objectId)")

    if task["isCompleted"] as NSObject == true {
            task["isCompleted"] = false
        } else {
            task["isCompleted"] = true
        }

    task.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            println("saved checkbox object in background")
        } else {
            println(error!.userInfo)
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {

        var task:PFObject = self.taskObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

        task.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

            self.fetchAllObjects()

            self.taskObjects.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        })

    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with tables and collection views, all the objects you have in a custom cell can be easily accessed in cellForRowAtIndexPath (for UITables)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ActionCell

    var action = actions[indexPath.row] as Action

    cell.nameLabel?.text = action.name
    cell.listLabel?.text = action.list
    cell.dateLabel?.text = action.date
    cell.checkboxButton = action.isChecked
    cell.checkBoxButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"checkedImage"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    return cell
}
```

more over I would suggest to change constants to variables. I'm new to Swift too and "let" declares a static variable.

I find very cool the use of the conditional operator (?:) in these cases:

```
cell.checkBoxButton.setImage(UIImage(named:(any_boolean_condition ? "checkedImage" : "uncheckedImage")), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

so it can return one image name for the condition True and another name for the condition False.

Comment: Thanks, but I applied your code and received this error next to the cell.checkboxButton.setImage... '(UIButton) -> ()' does not have a member named 'setImage'

Comment: I guess you are confusing some objects. UIButton DOES have setImage method. If your compiler says not, then the variable referenced in cell.checkBoxButton is NOT an UIButton. Another point is that you are using a self.isChecked boolean variable whilst you can use the UIButton.selected and .isSelected states: I would set an image for the default state (unchecked image) and a selected one for the latter state and then just switch the UIButton.selected:

Comment: From Interface Builder control-click on the UIButton you must make sure you drag a reference from IB into your code.

Comment: if the answer was useful, please accept it as so :D

Comment: Very useful. I'm still planning to edit my question to show my working code to future Googlers, but I guess there's no reason I can't accept it now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In this code

func imageForCheckbox(checkbox:Bool) -> UIImage? {
    var checkbox = false
    if checkbox {    self.setImage(UIImage(named:"checkedImage"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        self.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheckedImage"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}

you are using SELF but self in this case is a UITableViewController and of course it has no method setImage.